# Trying to join a friends Minecraft server and will not let me: They are on a different network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

My friend who lives in another neighborhood is making a server for MC Eternal modpack and I keep getting the "io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out" message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you weren't able to connect and play at all, please clarify if you were able to play, but got disconnected multiple times.

You might try setting up Hamachi. You can create a VLAN, and once you are in one "Hamachi network", you'll be able to connect via your friend's Hamachi IP (The one that starts with 25).

Or if your friend has access to his/her router, he/she might try port forwarding the port of minecraft (by default 25565). You can find countless tutorials on how to do this on google by searching "port forwarding ".